# How to change the shape of buttons from c# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I make the game 4 in a row. When starting the application, the user can choose the shape of the discs. Here the user can choose from a circle, square or triangle.
[Screenshot start application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yraQQ.jpg)

The discs are actually buttons in code. I have already succeeded in creating a round button using the xaml code.

```xml
<Button x:Name="disk_4C" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="60" IsEnabled="False" Click="Disk_click">
     <Button.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="100" />
          </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

But now the buttons are always round. Actually, the intention is that the user can choose the shape himself. So the shape of the buttons should be adjustable from within the c# code. In fact, something like the following should be possible:

```
disk_4C.Shape = Triangle;
```

Does anyone know how I could do this? All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Set different Button Templates, either by setting the Template property of by setting different Styles with different ControlTemplates.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369844/how-to-change-the-shape-of-button

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your answer. But how does this work exactly? Do you have an example?

Comment: There are plenty of examples here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `DynamicResource` markup extension to reference the template. This way you can easily swap in and out resources:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Template"
          Value="{DynamicResource ShapedButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" 
                 TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Grid>
    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="SquareButtonTemplate"
                 TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
               Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    ChangeButtonShapeToRound();
  }

  private void ChangeButtonShapeToSquared()
    => Application.Current.Resources["ShapedButtonTemplate"] = Application.Current.Resources["SquareButtonTemplate"];

  private void ChangeButtonShapeToRound()
    => Application.Current.Resources["ShapedButtonTemplate"] = Application.Current.Resources["RoundButtonTemplate"];
}
```